# Restrict bootstrap datepicker to select date upto 2 years - not working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to restrict the date which the user can select to 2 years from today’s date, by default user can select infinite date

Following is the code I have tried

**Libraries used:**

> ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
>
> maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6
>
> css/bootstrap.min.css css/datepicker.css
>
> maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js
>
> js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker1">

<script>
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
   endDate:'+2y'
});
</script>
```

The above code doesn't limit the date

Please help!!!

I have also tried the following code which is working but the datepicker in this case is an inline datepicker, I do not need an inline datepicker

```
<head>
http://192.168.0.27:8080/hostbook/public_html/js/jquery.js

http://192.168.0.27:8080/hostbook/public_html/assests/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css

http://192.168.0.27:8080/hostbook/public_html/assests/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
</head>

<input name="check_in" id="check_in" type="text" class="datepicker search-date"  autocomplete="off" />
               
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#check_in').datepicker({ format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
startView: "months",
endDate:'+2y',
})

});

</script>
```

Comment: Your code should work for both inline and embedded date-picker. See [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/Lvbsczk4/3/)

Comment: I need the datepicker as in this link http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/  ; The first one, it's kind of a popup. How do you restrict date in such format of datepicker ?

Comment: You mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/Lvbsczk4/4/)?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i don't know why my code didnt work

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified `startDate` for `datePicker` to decide `endDate`. Just add it in option as below:

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
   startDate:new Date(), //Today's Date
   endDate:'+2y'
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Lvbsczk4/1/)**

Comment: thanks but the code works only for an inline datepicker. I need the datepicker as in this link http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker.

Comment: There are multiple `datepickers` in that link.. which one you are talking about?

Comment: The first one. It is kind of a popup. How do you restrict date in such format of datepicker ?